# "And" vs "Or" in a list with a negative modifier

Tags: meaning, grammar, conjunctions, lists, coordinating-conjunctions

If a given set of instructions says, for example:

> Failure to complete assignments A, B, and C will result in punishment.

Does that indicate that failure to do all of those assignments and only all of those assignments will result in the punishment, or that failure to complete any of the assignments will result in punishment?

I feel like it would mean that one must fail to complete all of the assignments, and I want to say that the statement is equivalent to "Failure to complete A and Failure to complete B and failure to complete C...", but I am unable to find an example of that equivalency online.

I am also unsure of how the negative modifier comes into play. For instance, does the sentence mean "Failure to complete (A, B, and C)..." or does it mean "Failure to (complete A, B, and C)..." Is there even a definite interpretation of this sentence?

Comment: If it says _and_, the simple answer is that it means _and_. If you complete (say) assignments A and C but don't complete B, then you have not completed assignments A, B, **and** C. If you have tried, but have not completed all of them, then you have failed to complete them.

Comment: Is the statement "Failure to complete assignments A, B, and C will result in punishment." then the same as the statement "Failure to complete assignments A, B, or C will result in punishment."? I feel like your description of the statement is best suited by the version that says or.

Comment: And I want to add that the phrase does not say "You MUST complete assignments, A, B, and C..." in which case it is simply "and" and you'd be correct. However it begins with "Failure to complete", which I believe indicates that the sentence's intention signifies failure to complete assignments to receive a punishment, instead of simply needing to complete assignments to avoid punishment.

Comment: Plenty of people use this type of construction to mean that it is true of assignments A, B and C that failure to complete will lead to punishment - so in practical terms it is ambiguous. I would have thought there would be a parse that corresponds to that meaning, but in light of John Lawler's comment, maybe not.

Comment: You can parse it that way if you like, but it comes out the same either way. Finish all or be punished, your choice.

Comment: Again, I want to know if you think there is a difference between the phrases "Failure to complete assignments A, B, and C will result in punishment" and "Failure to complete assignments A, B, or C will result in punishment."

Answer (score 0):

> Failure to complete assignments A, B, and C will result in punishment.

means all three assignments must be completed: if one or more of them is not completed punishment will follow.

The construction "to complete assignments A, B, and C" is in the form of a [noun infinitive](http://www.dailygrammar.com/Lesson-220-Noun-Infinitives.htm) ("to complete") followed by  "assignments A, B, and C" as the object of complete. And "A", "B" and "C" are being used as [postpositive adjectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective) describing "assignments" in the plural.

While "failure" and "punishment" have negative connotations they are not boolean operators - trying to use boolean logic reduction as if they were appears more hopeful than warranted - and removing the negative terms does not significantly change the instruction. Consider that:

> Be sure to complete assignments A, B and C

does not mean the same thing to a teacher as

> Be sure to complete assignment A, B or C

and

> Be sure to complete assignments A, B or C

with assignments *in the plural* would need rewording to convey its meaning unambiguously .

Comment: If "Failure to complete assignments A, B, and C will result in punishment" results in punishment upon failure to complete one or more assignments, then what does the phrase "Failure to complete assignments A, B, or C will result in punishment" mean?

Comment: Usually "or" denotes one of a group and "assignments A, B or C" conflicts with this. The meaning of "Failure to complete assignments A, B, or C will result in punishment" is badly worded and needs further clarification of what it is supposed to mean from  its originator.